# iOS Localization, simulator and device always uses Base.lproj instead of users preferred locale

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dictionary, localization

I am creating an app that for now I would like to offer in **English and German**. I checked the Base localization mark in the project configuration and added `German`. I left English as the development language.

Then I created a file `Translation.plist` which basically consists of dictionaries that I call categories, e.g. I have one dictionary for button texts, label texts etc. Each of the category dictionaries again consists of dictionaries that contain two Strings: value and comment. Translation.plist is localized via `XCode`. The folders `Base.lproj`, `en.lproj` and `de.lproj` exist and contain a copy of the plist-file as expected.

Then I created a class `Translator.swift` that is supposed to load the `Translation.plist` file as an `NSDictionary` depending on the user's preferred locale. The code looks like this:

```
func relevantDictionary(category: String) -> NSDictionary {
    let preferredLocale = Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first ?? "Base"
    NSLog("User's preferred locale is \(preferredLocale)")
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Translation", withExtension: "plist") else {
        fatalError("Could not find Translation.plist")
    }

    NSLog("Using \(url.absoluteURL) for translation")
    guard let root = NSDictionary(contentsOf: url) else {
        fatalError("Could not find dictionary for category (locale=\(preferredLocale)")
    }

    guard let relevant = root.value(forKey: category) as? NSDictionary else {
        fatalError("Could not create dictionary from Translation.plist")
    }

    return relevant
}
```

Then I created a String extension that uses the Translator as follows:

```
func localize(category: String) -> String {
    return Translator.instance.translate(category: category, string: self)
}
```

With this I call the Translator by "yes".localize("button"). In English I would expect "Yes", in German I would expect "Ja". The log says the following:

> 2017-07-05 08:45:24.728 myApp[13598:35048360] User's preferred locale is  de_DE
>
> 2017-07-05 08:45:24.728 myApp[13598:35048360] Using file:///Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A39D3318-943D-4EFE-BB97-5C2218279132/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4614E696-B52E-4C30-BBE8-3C76F6392413/myApp.app/Base.lproj/Translation.plist for translation

I wonder why this happens and what I have missed. I would have expected that `de.lproj/Translation.plist` is loaded instead of `Base.lproj/Translation.plist`.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you creating your own plist files in the first place? You should use `.strings` files shouldn't you?

Comment: I just feel more comfortable and flexible when I use plist-files. They are more powerful in terms of how I can organize my localizations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with single .plist file. You don't need to create different .plist files for it.

```
Firstly, Add English and German countries with locale in Project -> info
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4QIY.png

Once, you added countries with locale in Project -> info then add localizable.strings file in your bundle.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnjgL.png

At the end, just add country's locale in your language support class.

NSArray* languages = @[@"en", @"de"];`enter code here`
    NSString *current = [languages objectAtIndex:0];
    [self setLanguage:current];
```

Hope it would help you.

Comment: That means, that I would have to load all languages even though only one is needed. To me this seems to be expensive in terms of memory usage, right?  Anyway, is it possible to load localized plist-files or not? If yes, how can it be done?

Comment: @Martin, it's not expensive in term of memory usage.

Comment: I could just create one file per language with the file name containing the locale and load the right file depending on the user's preferred locale. That way I just load what is needed. Thanks for the hint anyway. :)