# Different locales returned by two different apps on the same simulator

Tags: ios, localization, ios-simulator, plist

coming from [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918890/ios-localization-simulator-and-device-always-uses-base-lproj-instead-of-users-p/44919702?noredirect=1#comment76825684_44919702) (1) I experience strange behaviors. I have two apps A and B that I run on the same simulator. When I call the following code `Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first` in A "de" is returned, but in B "de_DE" is returned. I wonder how this can be explained... Furthermore the same code coming from (1) works as expected in A but not in B. I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of the language fallback.

"de" means german in general also in Austria for example and "de_DE" means german for region Germany.

Maybe one of the apps has some settings for explicit German language and/or region fallback

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, you are right obviously. I explicitly added German(Germany) in my localizations and now the plist file from de-DE.lproj is used. I also changed the region in the simulator from Germany to US but left the first language German. Then the plist-file from de.lproj is loaded.